# Build Windows RCP Application on Unix Machine

Tags: eclipse, build, rcp, pde

We're trying to do an Eclipse PDE build for a RCP Application via Hudson/Jenkins. We were doing this so far successfully on a Windows machine (Hudson running on Windows Server 2003). We have decided to move our CI system to a unix machine. 
When executing the same build on the unix machine our build fails with the following error:

```
!SESSION 2011-04-12 01:00:49.497 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_23
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=sparc, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -buildfile /appl/midw/jenkins/jobs/AP_NAPF/workspace/TP/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.4.1.R34x_v20081217/scripts/build.xml main -Ddummy=true
Command-line arguments:  -ws win32 -os win32 -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -buildfile /appl/midw/jenkins/jobs/AP_NAPF/workspace/TP/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.4.1.R34x_v20081217/scripts/build.xml main -data /appl/midw/jenkins/jobs/AP_NAPF/workspace/ap_build/workspace -Ddummy=true

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-04-12 01:00:58.961
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench (687).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin for bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:980)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:980)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1274)
    at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntCorePreferences$WrappedClassLoader.findClass(AntCorePreferences.java:115)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.AntClassLoader.loadClassPlugins(AntClassLoader.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:47)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.start(AntRunner.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1236)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1212)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:141)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 67 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
```

I've already tried a couple of things after moving to the new infrastructure, with no avail:

- Use a different rt.jar (one coming from a windows JRE) for the PDE build using the `bootclasspath` property.
- Changning the `-os` command line argument to: `solaris`

Is it at all possible to do a RCP build for a Windows application on a Unix machine?
If yes, is it necessary to change any parameters when launching the PDE build?

Note: We're using [pluginbuilder](http://www.pluginbuilder.org/) to setup the PDE build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eclipse you are using to execute the PDE build (i.e. the org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner application) must be executable in your build server environment. You said that you are executing the build on a Unix machine, but the ws and os parameters are set to win32. So it seems that you use a Windows version of Eclipse on your Unix build server. This can't work since the Unix-specific fragments usually are not available there (needed for example for SWT, that's why the class SWTError is not found).

You should download an Eclipse from eclipse.org which is specific to your environment on your build server (OS, windowing system and processor architecture) and use it to run the PDE build.

Comment: Setting `os=solaris`, `ws=sgtk` and `arch=sparc` got rid of the SWTError. I'm hitting a next road block though :-(. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Download [eclipse delta pack](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/index.php#DeltaPack), unzip it into your target eclipse before starting PDE build.

Comment: Unfortunately, including native libraries from delta package in your target doesn't mean those are automatically deployed along when you let equinox put together platform-specific builds. As a workaround, you can simply copy the respective library (e.g. `org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_xxx.jar` for a `linux.gtk.x86_64` build)
from delta package's plugin directory into the plugin directory of your freshly exported build, manually. Because apparently that's what a bundle framework is for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the eclipse that you are using to do the build from the eclipse install that you are putting together with your build. The first one needs to be correct for your build OS. Take a look at your PDE Build invocation. There are separate parameters for Eclipse install and target platform.